# Convert C# Lambda to vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, lambda

Need Help in converting this to VB.NET

```
   public void GetCustomers(Action<IEnumerable<Customer>> onSuccess, Action<Exception> onFail)
    {
        Manager.Customers.ExecuteAsync(op =>
              {
                  if (op.CompletedSuccessfully)
                  {
                      if (onSuccess != null) 
                          onSuccess(op.Results);
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      if (onFail != null)
                      {
                          op.MarkErrorAsHandled();
                          onFail(op.Error);
                      }
                  }
              }
           );
    }
```

Comment: Note, there is no multi line anonymous delegate (lambda) support for VB 9

Comment: Am I hallucinating? I do this at work often. Let me go look it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do in-line anonymous functions/subs with syntax like:

```
Manager.Customers.ExecuteAsync( Sub (op)
                                  If op.CompletedSuccessfully Then
                                    ...
                                  Else
                                    ...
                                  EndIf
                                End Sub )
```

Sometimes things get really flakey when you use it inline, so when that happens I give the local sub/function a name:

```
Dim SomeFun as Action(Of OpType) = Sub (op)
                                     ...
                                   End Sub
```

This works well because you can still close over your lexical environment.

This is all from memory - I don't have VS at home (and I try not to troll SO at work). In particular, I'm not sure I have my closing paren in the right place.

MSDN [Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531253.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I'm still having overload resolution error.

Comment: I've finally found the error on the overloaded method. Thanks for the help

Comment: Does VB always generate a new delegate each time inline anonymous methods are used, or can an inline method that doesn't use "Me" (explicitly or implicitly) be kept as a single delegate shared by the class?